# Azure Pipeline - Control deployment with SonarQube Quality Gates

Tags: sonarqube, azure-pipelines, cicd

I am using Azure yaml pipeline with SonarQube and here's how my pipeline is setup:

```
                - checkout: self
                - task: SonarQubePrepare@5
                  displayName: 'SonarQube - Prepare'
                  inputs:
                    SonarQube: '$(sonarQubeConnection)'
                    scannerMode: 'CLI'
                    configMode: 'manual'
                    cliProjectKey: $(sonarQubeProject)
                    cliProjectName: $(sonarQubeProject)
                    #cliSources: '.'

                - script: |
                    sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php$(phpVersion)
                    sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar$(phpVersion)
                    sudo update-alternatives --set phpdbg /usr/bin/phpdbg$(phpVersion)
                    sudo update-alternatives --set php-cgi /usr/bin/php-cgi$(phpVersion)
                    sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar$(phpVersion)
                    php -version
                  workingDirectory: $(rootFolder)
                  displayName: 'Use PHP version $(phpVersion)'

                - script: composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist
                  workingDirectory: $(rootFolder)
                  displayName: 'Composer install'

                - task: SonarQubeAnalyze@5
                  displayName: 'SonarQube - Analysis'

                - task: SonarQubePublish@5
                  displayName: 'SonarQube - Publish Quality Gate Result'
                  inputs:
                    pollingTimeoutSec: $(sonarQubePollingTimeout)

                - script: echo "After code scan..."
                  displayName: 'Test Message'
```

But I see it runs ALL steps irrespective of the result from Quality Gate - the 'Test Message' shows up even when the quality gate fails.

[image]

[image]

Here's my Quality Gate in SonarQube:

[image]

I want to run subsequent steps from 'SonarQube - Publish Quality Gate Result' only when its "Passed" - please advise.

PS - I am using the DVWA app from GitHub - https://github.com/digininja/DVWA

Comment: Looks like there's an extension that does exactly this:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimondeLang.sonar-buildbreaker

But unfortunately, its not official and I'll have tough time getting approval to use this!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we can invoke REST API and throw exception if the status is not OK:

http://SonarFQDN:9000/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=SonarProjectKey